# Does dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier work with ARC?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios5, automatic-ref-counting, uistoryboard

In iOS5, using ARC and prototype cells for tableView on storyboard, can I replace the code below:

```
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] 
      initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault 
      reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}

// Configure the cell...
return cell;
```

With this simple code?:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView 
  dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell"];
return cell;
```

I saw this on this link:

http://www.raywenderlich.com/5138/beginning-storyboards-in-ios-5-part-1

Thank's in advance!

Comment: Yes, you can. Also, it doesn't require ARC. You can use the new pattern as long as you're using iOS 5 and storyboards.

Comment: @JasonCoco: This should be an answer, not a comment.

Comment: @JasonCoco  I don't get why, but this thing doesn't work for me. I keep getting a "nil" cell. I create a new master-detail project. The example works great. When I add the cellForRowIndexPath method and table size method and set the size to be 2 I get an exception, since the dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier keep getting me "nil".

Comment: @Moonlight In your storyboard, you need to make sure that you create a prototype cell and that you give it the same identifier in IB as you do in code (in your case, `Cell`). It's case sensitive, so it must be named `Cell` with a capital 'C' and you should have only one prototype cell in your storyboard with that name.

Comment: @JasonCoco  yes,i think i did all these things but i still return nil cell.  this is a demo code http://www.ericyue.info/Circle.zip

Comment: @JasonCoco   run the demo,and click the left button on the navigatebar

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This problem is happening because you aren't creating the `MenuViewController` from the storyboard.  You are creating it like this:

```
MenuViewController *menuViewController = [[MenuViewController alloc] init];
```

That instance of `MenuViewController` isn't connected to the storyboard, so it doesn't know about the prototype cells in the storyboard.

You need to go into your storyboard and set the identifier of the `MenuViewController` there to something like `menuViewController`.  Then you can create an instance like this:

```
MenuViewController *menuViewController =  [self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"menuViewController"];
```

Comment: thank you！it works:)  is there any way to creating the MenuViewController from the storyboard directly?

Comment: Disconnect the bookmarks button (in the Timeline navigation bar) from the `MenuButtonPressed:` method.  Control-drag from the bookmarks button to the `MenuViewController` instance in the storyboard and choose `Push` or `Modal` as the segue type.

Answer (score 0):

My solution was finally like this:

```
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier
                                                          forIndexPath:indexPath];

cell = [cell initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
```

Because form iOS 5.0 onwards the first line of code will never produce a nil value, and I saw no other way to specify the style I wanted. Or, I could have Added an instance of Table View Controller from the library, and then I could edit the style in the prototype cell.

Comment: No, this is inefficient and suggests misunderstanding about how cell class is associated with identifier. If the dequeue method is not returning `nil`, that's because you either (a) have associated a storyboard cell prototype with that identifier; (b) you used `registerClass:forCellReuseIdentifier:`; or (c) you previously did `initWithStyle:reusedIdentifier:` and it successfully dequeued cell. Nowadays, you would generally use option (a), and modify the storyboard so that the cell prototype has the appropriate style. Then you'd eliminate your second line of code.

Comment: Thanks Rob. My code is case (b), I can't find a way to set the cell's style.

Comment: If you used `registerClass`, your subclass should implement `initWithStyle` which calls `[super initWithStyle:...]`, but explicitly specifying the appropriate style, rather than just passing along the provided `UITableViewCellStyle`. But the above code sample is inadvisable because it will result in `initWithStyle` being called twice (because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier` will call `initWithStyle` itself if there's no cell available for reuse, but you're then calling it again).