# Adding subtitle style to Table View Cell in XCode 4.3.3

Tags: iphone, uitableview

I have a problem which makes me crazy. I think it is very easy to solve but I could not figure it out. I made a simple table view which has cells according two arrays. One is for main text in a cell, the other one is for subtitles in a cell. But the problem is When I make my cells with subtitle style, I can't see them when I run the application.
Here is my code:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

if ( cell == nil){
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc]initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleSubtitle reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
    }
    cell.textLabel.text = [hop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = [hop2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}
```

When I debugging I realize that when the program reaches the if block, it does not go into block. Which means "cell" is not nil at that moment. Question is why is that happening and how can I solve this? All your help will be appreciated.

Comment: Try to put `NSLog(@"%@",[hop objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);` and `NSLog(@"%@",[hop2 objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]);` before `cell.textLabel.text=...` and check in the console if are not nil.

Comment: They are not nil. The problem is the app does not go into if statement. And that makes detailTextLabel not to be there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are using iOS5 and storyboards. Then `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` gives a valid cell back even if there isn't one in the reuse stack. Try to edit you cell in storyboard.

This [stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9142817/does-dequeuereusablecellwithidentifier-work-with-arc) should help you to understand what happens.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand what is going on there. That guy's problem is he is getting a nil cell. And someone told him MenuViewController. What is that?

Comment: No. The link is to a stackoverflow post about the new behavior of 'dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:' with iOS 5. Did you see the link in the question?

Comment: I saw that but it is not opened. On the other hand, when you said try to edit the cell, I saw the table view cell properties.There is options which has table view cell styles. I think it is new and we don't need to implement table view style in coding part. So, my problem is solved. Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes, this is new to iOS5. And it is needed because `dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:` will always return a valid cell if there is a storyboard file (as far as I know).

Answer (score 0):

Check your Array data.I think you not properly insert into array. Otherwise you are not initialize array

Comment: That is not the problem. Arrays are fine. The problem is the app does not go into if statement.